# Как ReCAPTCHA v3 определяет, что бот это бот?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, phantomjs, recaptcha

Как **ReCAPTCHA v3** определяет, что бот это бот?
Решил написать бота при помощи phantomjs и библиотеки casperjs, добавил параметр viewport, который 1920х1080, добавил userAgent

```
(Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.86 YaBrowser/20.8.0.903 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36)
```

но score равен 0.1. После этого решил написать бота при помощи selenium + firefox (при том, что указан параметр headless), там score равен 0.3, как так?
Получил куки от 2-ого бота и вставил их в 1-ого (phantomjs). Сеть также пробовал мониторить, но никаких значимых различий между firefox и phantomjs не заметил.

**phantomjs**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

phantom.addCookie([
  {
    name: 'evohqq74u',
    value: 'rvavsej8kka27ocdogesqhkj87',
    path: '/',
    domain: 'antcpt.com',
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },
  {
    name: '_ym_uid',
    value: '159883072824193045',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1630366727,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },{
    name: '_ym_d',
    value: '1598830728',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1630366727,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },
  {
    name: '_ym_isad',
    value: '2',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1598902728,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },{
    name: '_ga',
    value: 'GA1.2.137458170.1598830728',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1661902728,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },
  {
    name: '_gid',
    value: 'GA1.2.1709358714.1598830728',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1598917128,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },{
    name: '_gat_gtag_UA_86572429_1',
    value: '1',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1598830788,
    sameSite: 'None'
  },
  {
    name: '_ym_visorc_40574825',
    value: 'w',
    path: '/',
    domain: '.antcpt.com',
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    expiry: 1598832528,
    sameSite: 'None'
  }
]);

casper.start();
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.86 YaBrowser/20.8.0.903 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36');
casper.viewport(1920, 1080);

casper.thenOpen('https://antcpt.com/rus/information/demo-form/recaptcha-3-test-score.html', function(status) {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        casper.capture('screenshot.png');
    });
});

casper.run();
```

**selenium + firefox**

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const until = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/until');

const screen = {
  width: 1240,
  height: 720
};

let option = new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize(screen);

let driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(option)
    .build();

try {
    driver.get('https://antcpt.com/rus/information/demo-form/recaptcha-3-test-score.html').then(
        () => {

            driver.manage().getCookies()
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    );
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Некоторое собрание информации на эту тему можно найти тут: https://github.com/paulirish/headless-cat-n-mouse